# Socket.io Messages getting buffered and delivered together on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

I have a Node.js game server that delivers updates to clients every 50 ms using socket.io (websockets only, long-polling is disabled). This usually works perfectly fine -- the server emits every 50 ms and clients receive the updates ~50ms apart.

I noticed recently that in Chrome (it seems like this doesn't happen in any other browser... Safari, Opera, Firefox, etc) updates will no longer be received every 50 ms *when the client is emitting messages to the server*. If the client is emitting messages frequently to the server (10+ times per second), the client will receive no server updates for ~700 ms at a time and then suddenly receive all 14 missed messages one after another (~1ms apart). For example:

Server send timestamps:
`0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700`

Normal receipt timestamps:
`0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700`

Timestamps when client is emitting:
`0, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710`

Again, this is not normal behavior. The client should have plenty of time to receive and process an update once every 50 ms. My computer is a high end computer that has no problem keeping up with this, plus this works perfectly fine on every other browser I tested as far as I know.

Any ideas?

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution to  this problem?